# Install IE8 Add-on in Windows 7 from .cab file

Tags: windows-7, browser-addons, internet-explorer-8

I have an Internet Explorer add-on that is a `.cab` file which contains a `.dll` and a `.inf`. Does anyone know how I can install this as an IE add-on? I've tried the most obvious: drag-and-drop, extracting and right-clicking the .inf file and clicking "Install", but neither work.

Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

All the add ons for IE8 are installers, It looks like it is a cab file used in conjunction with an IE8 customization tool, used for customizing IE8 when it is deployed with the OS during installation.

Nlite, an XP customizer also uses a cab file to integrate IE8 into the image.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/cc889351.aspx